# Cordova hot code push not working on production server

Tags: android, cordova

I am building a Cordova app and trying to use hot code push plugin for future update. It's working fine on the local server, but it does nothing when trying to use with the production server.

- I have added

  ```
  <chcp>
      <config-file url="https://my-server.com/app/chcp.json"/>
  </chcp>
  ```

to config.xml.

- I am creating the config file with `cordova-hcp init`.
- Building config with `cordova-hcp build`.
- Installing app with `cordova run`.
- Changing the `www/index.html` file a little.
- Rebuilding with `cordova-hcp build`.
- Uploading the resulting `www/*` files to the designated url, `https://my-server.com/app/`.
- Launching the previously installed app.

However nothing happens, although the server files are obviously different from the device files. And yes I have checked the network connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to guess regarding your described workflow.

But best would be to check what actually is happening regarding the native code's logs.

Therefore just check for log output containing the "CHCP" string. As for Android you may use:

```
$ adb logcat | grep CHCP
```

**So now to guess:**

1. Before uploading your files to the server, make sure to run

   $ cordova-hcp build

again as otherwise your build version inside chcp.json would still be the same even though your files changed.

2. Make sure you do not leave out some files due to a misfunctioning .chcpignore file.

As for me then it was the case that IDE files have been tracked by chcp to the chcp.manifest, but of course I did not upload them to the server as they should basically be ignored.

So check your chcp.manifest if it only contains files which actually end up on the server.

3. Make sure, that your app config.xml includes:

   < access origin="https://my-server.com/app/*" />